# Can't create Primary Key-Foreign Key relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, foreign-keys, migration

I am trying to create a primary key-foreign key relation using in laravel, but I keep getting this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `volga_2`.`employees` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `employees` add constraint `employees_dept_id_foreign` foreign key (`dept_id`) references `departments` (`id`))
```

I cant seem to find out where am I going wrong, since I have made changes into the schema, after looking at other answers on SO.

When I run `php artisan migrate` the error above pops up, and its a partial migration.

Any pointers into this would be awesome, since I have been looking for a while for a solution to this!

Thanks!

**Employee Table**

```
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('dept_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('dept_id')->references('id')->on('departments');
            $table->integer('salary_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('salary_id')->references('id')->on('salary');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->timestamp('date_of_joining');
            $table->dateTime('date_of_birth');
            $table->timestamps();
```

Departments Table

```
Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('dept_name');
        $table->timestamps();
```

**Salaries Table**

```
Schema::create('salaries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('monthlySalary');
            $table->timestamps();
```

**Added:**
**DB Seeder.**

```
factory(App\Employee::class, 25)->create()->each(function ($employee) {
            $department = factory(App\Department::class)->make();
            $employee->department()->save($department);
            $salary = factory(App\Salary::class)->make();
            $employee->salary()->save($salary);
        });
```

**Changed DB Seeder based on comment**

```
factory(App\Department::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($department) {
            $salary = factory(App\Salary::class)->make();
            $department->salary()->save($salary);
            $employee = factory(App\Employee::class)->make();
            $salary->employee->save($employee);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the tables you are referencing in your `employees` migration already exist, so they can actually be referenced. You can do this by renaming the file/changing the date part in the filename of your `employees` migration to come after your `departments` and `salaries` migration.

You also need to change

```
$table->foreign('salary_id')->references('id')->on('salary');
```

to

```
$table->foreign('salary_id')->references('id')->on('salaries');
```

to reflect the same table name you used in your `salaries` migration.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the salary->salaries typo. 
I have updated the question above to include the DBSeeder script that I am currently using. I changed it so that Database and Salaries are created first, but still the same error.

Comment: Seeders are irrelevant to this question and the error you get. `php artisan migrate` doesn't seed the database. If your migrations work and you have a different problem with seeders now, please create a new question for your seeder problem.

Comment: I thought that seeders and migrations did the same thing..clearly I was wrong! Thank you! I have marked your answer as the correct one!

Comment: Nope, migrations create/alter tables/foreignkey-relations in your database. Seeders "_seed_" those tables with random/fake data so you have something to work with. You can run `php artisan db:seed` to seed the data _after_ you ran your migrations. On your DEV system you can run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` to delete all your data in the database and run all migrations from the start and also run all your seeders. DO NOT RUN THIS ON A PRODUCTION environment, since it'll delete all of your data